# change txt files in a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question. I have a folder of txt files as follows:

1.txt

```
3      0.5   0.3    0.05    0.09
0      0.5   0.8    0.08    0.1
```

desired output:

```
0      0.5   0.3    0.05    0.09
0      0.5   0.8    0.08    0.1
```

The lines in the txt file may vary from one line to 10 lines.
And if the index is zero, it remains the same

I want to convert non-zero indexes to zero using Python and do this for all files. How can I do this?

Comment: Where do you want to put your output? To stdout, to the same file or to some another file?

Answer (score 0):

Someone probably has a better way, but this works for me:

```
import fileinput

def process(line):
    end = line[line.find(" "):]
    print("0" + end, end="")

with fileinput.input("1.txt", inplace=1) as f:
    for line in f:
        process(line)
```

*fileinput redirects stdout (print) to the file when inplace=1*